# Find documents with $gte or $lte which has numbers as string values in arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection that contains documents as follows:

```json
{
 "_id": ObjectId(.....),
 "name": "John",
 "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "henry",
      "age": "22"
    },
    {
      "name": "merry",
      "age": "12"
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to find documents which have `contacts.age` is less than 20. I tried the following mongo query but had no luck. Anyone can help me out?

```java
document.Users.find({'$expr':{'$lte': [{'$toInt':'$contacts.age'}, '20'] }})
```

Above query gives following error:

```
Query failed with error code 241 and error message 'Executor error during find command :: 
caused by :: 
Unsupported conversion from array to int in $convert with no onError value' on server
```

Comment: i think you missed a `$` before `toInt`

Comment: This gives an error message again. I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Do you want all `contacts` if one of them contains the condition, or the array `contacts` filtered with only values where the condition is matched?

Comment: I want all the documents(existing full document) which have `contacts.age` greater than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all document (without change anything) you can try this aggregation query:

The trick here is to get only documents where there is one `true` in the array returned from condition `"$lte": [{"$toInt": "$$this"},20]`.

That's mean that only will be matched documents which has an array with a value (minimum one subdocument) matched.

**EDIT** with the final working example, using two ways to ensure the data:

- Using `"contacts": { "$ne": null }` into `$match` stage just before the `$expr` to avoid map over null.
- Using [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) to be able to use `onError` and `onNull` in case any value is not a number and can't be converted.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "contacts": {
        "$ne": null
      },
      "$expr": {
        "$in": [
          true,
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$contacts",
              "in": {
                "$lte": [
                  {
                    "$convert": {
                      "input": "$$this.age",
                      "to": "int",
                      "onError": "",
                      "onNull": ""
                    }
                  },
                  30
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bvKGa_N_fel)

Comment: This works. How can I update the above aggregation to filter `$contacts.age` if only exists or not empty in a document?

Comment: Because for me this gives `Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: No digits' on server` error.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want, can you add an example and expected output?

Comment: Can you check this [sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VRKWa4saxHC)? There can be some documents which empty or null of `contacts.age` field.

Comment: You can add a condition in the `$match` stage. just before the `$expr` checking if contacts is null. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g_-4n2jOHYk)

Comment: Can you explain to me why I get this error when I run the above sample code with MongoDriver? It gives 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Failed to parse number '' in $convert with no onError value: No digits'. Same error gives with the mongo compass aggregation view.

Comment: Maybe is there a value which is not a number? Then try to use `$convert` with `onError` and/or `onNull` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3FsR1hT1ma5)

Comment: Note that you can also use `""` in `onError` and `onNull`, not only numbers, [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bvKGa_N_fel)